# Permissions in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, windows-installer, file-permissions

I am making a call to:
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified); 
and this call works fine in Windows XP.

When I run it in Vista I get:

> Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\2lqfj0cv.tmp' is denied. (C:\Windows\system32\MsiExec.config) ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\2lqfj0cv.tmp' is denied.

Now I guss the pertinent fact here is that I am running the call above from a Windows Installer MSI (call to a managed DLL).  I guess I need to do something to up the user permissions?  I really don't know a lot about Vista permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using run as admin.  Also do you mean to be editing the MSIEXEC.config?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: Set the required execution level of the Setup.exe of my installer to "Administrator".  Works just fine now.